# when page load button click

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have 3 buttons and 3 panels. When I click the first button, panel 1 loads but panel2 and 3 are invisible, but 3 buttons always visible. When I click the button corresponding panel only loads and the page also refreshes every 60 seconds.

My problem is when page refresh this button and panels invisible and gridview load, because in pageload I call gridview but in page refresh I dont want to load gridview last click button and the corresponding panel will only stay in this page

Is this possible in jquery or session?

Comment: Are you Using any UpdatePanel?

Comment: you can check this http://forums.asp.net/t/1176832.aspx/1

Comment: no not using update panel.

Comment: It's very difficult to follow this description.  Can you provide a simple example of what you're doing and indicate where in the code the behavior is deviating from the expected result?  It doesn't even sound like you're using jQuery for anything, the terminology sounds more like the native ASP.NET server controls.

Comment: Maybe you should look here : http://www.thomasfrank.se/sessionvars.html

Answer (score 0):

```
Yes you can do this with jQuery .e.g.

$(function() {
            $("#btnA").click(function() {
var panel = $("#<%= PanelA.ClientID %>");

 if ($(panel).is(':visible')) {
                $(panel).fadeOut('slow');

}

else {

$(panel).fadeIn('slow');

}
            });
        });
```